# Switch/Case to change Title not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to change the title depending on the environment value. But now no titles are displayed.

appConfig.json

```
"env": "stage",
```

app.component.ts

```
env: string;

constructor(
    private configService: ConfigService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.environment = this.configService.config.env;
};
```

app.component.html

```
<ng-template [ngSwitch]="env">
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'production'">Title Production</span>
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'stage'">Title Stage</span>
    <span *ngSwitchDefault>Title Default</span>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Using env in your template, but this.environment in ngOnInit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using ng-container(or div) instead of ng-template as a host element for ngSwitch directive.

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="env">
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'production'">Title Production</span>
    <span *ngSwitchCase="'stage'">Title Stage</span>
    <span *ngSwitchDefault>Title Default</span>
</ng-container>
```